# Declaring concept for method with param

Tags: c++, c++20

I tried declaring the concept below, but MSVC 16.8 gives a compiler error. I trying to create a concept for a class that contains function: `bool Serialize(Archiver&)`
Am I declaring the concept wrong, or is MSVC broken?

```
struct Archiver {};

template<typename T>
concept Serializable = requires(T t) {
    {t.Serialize(Archiver&)} -> std::same_as<bool>; // This gives compiler error.
};

struct SomeClass {
    bool Serialize(Archiver&) { return true; }
};

template<Serializable S>
bool DoSerial(S& s) {
    Archiver a;
    return s.Serialize(a);
}

TEST_CASE("Call serializable class") {
    SomeClass s;
    CHECK(DoSerial(s) == true);
}
```

EDIT: (error list)

Concepts.cpp(223,27): error C2760: syntax error: unexpected token ')', expected 'expression'
Concepts.cpp(223,27): error C2760: syntax error: unexpected token ')', expected '}'
Concepts.cpp(239,5): error C2672: 'DoSerial': no matching overloaded function found
Concepts.cpp(239,5): error C7602: 'DoSerial': the associated constraints are not satisfied
Concepts.cpp(232): message : see declaration of 'DoSerial'

Comment: "_Am I declaring the concept wrong, or is MSVC broken?_" There's another possibility - MSVC doesn't yet support this functionality (Note: I didn't check documentation whether it does, or not. I just wanted to mention this as additional possibility).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the correct syntax. In the requires-expression, the expression in each compound requirement `{ expression } -> requirement;` should be a valid expression, not just a "syntax description". You probably want something more like this:

```cpp
template<typename T>
concept Serializable = requires(T t, Archiver a) {
    {t.Serialize(a)} -> std::same_as<bool>;
};
```

[Live example (albeit with GCC)](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b0f827424b2e7c31)

The error message was due to MSVC trying to parse `Archiver&)` as a bitwise-and operation with no valid syntactic term on the RHS.